# OnClick on div element works only in part of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, toggle

I started creating website a few days ago and now i met my first real problem:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

function myLama(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  display                : inline-block;
  margin-right           : 6%    !important; 
  float                  : right !important;
  padding-top            : 0px   !important;
  margin-top             : -40px !important;
  cursor                 : pointer;
  }
.dropdown {
  position               : relative;
  display                : inline-block;
  float                  : right;
  top                    : 40px;
  right                  : 6%;
  }
.dropdown-content {
  display                : none;
  min-width              : 14px;
  box-shadow             : 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index                : 1;
  border-radius          : 25px;
  width                  : 10%;
  float                  : right;
  margin-right           : 33px;
  }
.dropdown-content a {
  color                  : white;
  padding                : 12px 16px;
  text-decoration        : none;
  display                : block;
  border                 : 2px solid white;
  border-radius          : 25px;
  font-size              : 20px;
  margin-top             : 5px;
  }
.dropdown-content a      : hover {
  background-color       : #ffffff10;
  backdrop-filter        : blur(12px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
  }
.show {
  display                : block;
  }
.btn {
  -ms-touch-action       : manipulation;
  touch-action           : manipulation;
  cursor                 : pointer;
  -webkit-user-select    : none;
  -moz-user-select       : none;
  -ms-user-select        : none;
  user-select            : none;
  }
.komorka {
  background-color       : #ffffff10;
  backdrop-filter        : blur(12px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
  min-width              : 110px;
  box-shadow             : 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index                : 1;
  border-radius          : 25px;
  width                  : 10%;
  border                 : 2px solid white;
  color                  : white;
  margin-left            : auto;
  margin-right           : auto;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="dropbtn" onclick="myLama(this); myFunction()">
    <div onclick="myFunction()">
      <div class="bar1" ></div>
      <div class="bar2" ></div>
      <div class="bar3" ></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" class="komorka">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="komorka">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="komorka">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript works perfectly but why it works only when i click on the part of it and not when i click wherever i want on the element?

I want to solve it, can anyone help me?

[here it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XArqu.png)
[image]

[here it doesnt work because i didint click on right spot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmlUJ.png)

[image]

Comment: You code does not produce the output you describe or what's in the images. Please edit your post to create the [example] you've described. Please remove anything (css) not directly related to your question.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, you can Right Click>Inspect the place where the click doesn't work, and you can check if that location is actually the div. Maybe there's an element over the div that's intercepting the clicks (some elements will do that, even if there isn't an onclick assigned to it).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will work but you can try to add some width and height to the .dropbtn class like so:

```
.dropbtn {
    width: 50px; /*change to the size you need*/
    height: 50px; /*change to the size you need*/
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, it just moves the dropdown by 50 pixels down and left